# Problems with ISymbologyControl LoadDesktopStyleFile and installed ArcGIS Desktop 10

Tags: styles, desktop, arcgis, graphical-programming

I am sorry for my bad english. I use C++ and Qt framework for programm development. I call method 
ISymbologyControl LoadDesktopStyleFile and receive error code: "1075 800a0433 : ArcGIS Desktop is not installed 
on this machine so Style files cannot be read", but I have installed ArcGIS Desktop 10.0. I use 
esriLicenseProductCodeArcEditor license product code for initialize license:

```
IAoInitializePtr ipInit(CLSID_AoInitialize);
::AoInitialize(NULL);
esriLicenseStatus lic;
pIAoInit->Initialize(esriLicenseProductCodeArcEditor,&lic);
```

Program starts and works normally, but all of ArcObjects depends on ArcGIS Desktop don't work. When I used 
ArcGIS 9.3 everything worked. I use #import directive for use desktop libraries, such as:

```
 #import c:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.0\\com\\esriDisplayUI.olb raw_interfaces_only raw_native_types no_namespace, named_guids
```

for all required libraries. It works in 9.3 but doesn't work now in 10.0.
What is incorrect in my actions?